# What is <built-in> in C++ preprocessor output?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

**Summary**: C++ preprocessor output includes some lines that say `<built-in>`. I'm curious to know what these are for.

**Details**:

When I compile the following code in a file named `test.cpp` with `clang++ -E` (output from `g++` is similar):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

the first few lines of output are as follows:

> # 1 "test.cpp"
>       # 1 "test.cpp" 1
>       # 1 "<built-in>" 1
>       # 1 "<built-in>" 3
>       # 156 "<built-in>" 3
>       # 1 "<command line>" 1
>       # 1 "<built-in>" 2
>       # 1 "test.cpp" 2

My question is what do the `<built-in>` statements mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macro expands to "1", and in case of built-in, the macro is defined by default, e.g., `__cplusplus`, in case of command line, the macro is defined on the command-line, i.e., `-DMACRO=1`.

You can see a list of predefined macros:

```
cpp -dM foo.h
```

Comment: it looks like I also need the -E switch to get a human readable output, at least for a `.cpp` file. Also does the order that the output appears correspond to which macro is applied? In the test case I included I'm trying to figure out what `# 156 "<built-in>" 3` is doing.

Comment: The order corresponds to the order the macros are applied. Try the `-dN` flag, it should help you track that 156.